# Can not override bootstrap active class for button

Tags: html, css, button

I have bootstrap button. I add a new class to it. Change CSS. But I can't change css when button is clicked.

[image]

```css
.btn-funds {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  color: #d3b431;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #d3b431;
}

.btn-funds:active {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #d3b431;
  color: #efefef;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #d3b431;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 fund-text">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-funds">More details</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `!important` declaration?

Comment: Did you check if your stuff isn't override by bootstrap? Maybe you need !important? Also placement of the files inside header is importnat too.

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? The blue outline?

Comment: Important didn't help. Am I allowed to share a site I am working on? 
http://mezet.xyz/romeda/

One of the last sections on home contains these buttons.

Comment: Yes, I want to get rid of those blue lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
.btn-funds {
    outline: 0;
}
```

because that blue border is not a border, but an outline. Thats why it doesn't change.
I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Your code didn't followed the style, so you need to add `.btn` to properly target the button

```css
.btn.btn-funds {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  color: #d3b431;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #d3b431;
  outline: none;
}

.btn.btn-funds:active {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #d3b431;
  color: #efefef;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #d3b431;
  box-shadow: none
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 fund-text">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-funds">More details</button>
</div>
```